# Match key-value pattern regex

Tags: java, regex

I am making a key-value parser where the input string takes the form of `key:"value",key2:"value"`. Keys can contain the characters `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` and values can contain any character but `:`, `,`,`"` and `\` need to be prefixed with a backslash. Commas are used to separate the key-value pairs but are not needed after the last pair.

So far I have `([a-zA-Z0-9]+):"(.*)"` which will match most keys and values but obviously it wont be able to handle more than a single pair or if any of the 'control' characters go unescaped. `(?<=\\)[:,"\\]` seems to match all escaped characters but it will not match any 'normal' characters.

Is there a way to check for comma separation and to match all escaped 'control' characters as well as normal ones? Is this something that would be better suited to implementation without regex or would this need multiple patterns in sequence?

Some examples:

input: `joe:"bread",sam:"fish"` output: `joe -> bread` `sam -> fish`

input: `joe:"Look over there\, it's a shark!",sam:"I like fish."` output: `joe -> Look over there, it's a shark!` `sam -> I like fish`

Comment: could you provide an example along with expected output?

Comment: Why dont you `input_string.split(",")` then loop results and `result.split(":")` then you have key -> val pairs in a loop to do as you please.

Comment: Can new line be part of a value? And how is it specified in the value?

Comment: @nhahtdh Any character can be part of the value and will be represented as itself unless it needs to be prefixed with a '\' because it is part of the formatting.

Comment: @gwillie I assume I could do it but I would need to get the index of the ',' and check to see if it was escaped first.

Comment: You are not clear about how the value part is specified. For example: How is newline and tab characters represented in the value part? What are **all** the escape sequences allowed?

Comment: @user2248702 str.split() does take a regex too ie `(?<!\\),` to split string on comma not followed by a `\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `\` followed by any character except for line terminator specifies the character immediately following it.

You can use the following regex to match all instances of key-value pairs:

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*+)\""
```

Add `\\s*` before and after `:` if you want to allow free spacing.

This is what the regex engine sees:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+):"((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*+)"
```

The quantifier `*` is made possessive `*+`, since the 2 branches `[^\\"]` and `\\.` are mutual exclusive (no string can be matched by both at the same time). It also avoids `StackOverflowError` in the Oracle's implementation of `Pattern` class.

Use the regex above in a Matcher loop:

```
Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*+)\"");
Matcher matcher = keyValuePattern.matcher(inputString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);

    // Process the escape sequences in the value string
    String value = matcher.group(2).replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");

    // ...
}
```

In general case, depending on the complexity of the escape sequences (e.g. `\n`, `\uhhhh`, `\xhh`, `\0`), you might want to write a separate function to parse them. However, with the assumption above, the one-liner suffices.

Note that this solution doesn't care about the separators, though. And it will skip on invalid input to the nearest match. In the example of invalid input below, the solution above will skip `abc:"` at the beginning and happily match `xyz:"text text"` amd  `more:"pair"` as key-value pairs:

```
abc:"xyz:"text text", more:"pair"
```

If this behavior is not desirable, there is a solution, but the string containing all the key-value pairs must be isolated first, instead of being part of a bigger string that doesn't have anything to do with key-value pairs:

```
"(?:^|(?!^)\\G,)([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*+)\""
```

Free-spacing version:

```
"(?:^\s*|(?!^)\\G\s*,\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*:\s*\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*+)\""
```

Comment: I ended up splitting the string into key-value pairs then using `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+):"((?:\\[:"\\,]|[^:"\\,])*)"$` thanks to your answer. Splitting it first allows me to give a more descriptive error if something goes wrong. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it but it seems to work for all test cases I have had and reject anything malformed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below regex to get the key value pair.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+):"(.*?)(?<!\\)"
```

OR

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+):"(.*?)"(?=,[a-zA-Z0-9]+:"|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/10)

Java regex would be,

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\""
```

`(?<!\\)"` negative lookbehind asserts that the double quotes won't be preceeded by a backslash character. In java, to match a backslash character, you need to escape the backslash in your pattern exactly three times, ie, `\\\\`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/9)

```
String s = "joe:\"Look over there\\, it's a shark!\",sam:\"I like fish.\"";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\"").matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " --> " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
joe --> Look over there\, it's a shark!
sam --> I like fish.
```

OR

```
String s = "joe:\"Look over there\\, i\\\"t's a shark!\",sam:\"I like fish.\"";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\"((?:\\\\\"|[^\"])*)\"").matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " --> " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
joe --> Look over there\, i\"t's a shark!
sam --> I like fish.
```

Comment: There are still problems, but I realize that there is no point in downvoting the answer, since the question is underspecified.

Comment: By the way, your regex will fail for `abc:"value\\"`

Comment: Why not the usual `(?:[^\\"]*+|\\.)*+`? Your solution is very brittle.

Comment: he fails to describe the escaped characters.

Comment: @AvinashRaj This will match a value that contains characters such as `"\,:` with no backslash prefixing them. While this is OK most of the time in my situation it means that it will accept incorrectly formatted strings, do you know of a way to fix this?